# Generating code from truth tables!

Tags: php, code-generation, generator, truthtable

As odd as this question sounds, i've actually got a set of vairables and a few conditions in which they produce a valid state. i will of course write out the code that tests them based on my understanding, but is there a system / code generator that *generates* valid code with all proper optimizations?

```
  $a   $b   Output
 ---------------
  0     0    1
  0     1    0
  1     0    1
  1     1    0
```

so this system shoudl generate the php code:

```
 if($b==0) {}
```

For this:

```
  $a   $b   Output
 ---------------
  0     0    0
  0     1    1
  1     0    1
  1     1    0
```

it should output:

```
 if(($a!=1 && $b!=1) && ($a!=0 && $b!=0)) {}
 // any better way?
```

Of course, 0 and 1 here is just for iillustration - there are actual strings/values that i need to compare with, so clever multiplication techniques wont work.

Comment: whats wrong with using true/false a switch or even elseif's

Comment: Btw the output for your second example should be `if($a==1 ^ $b==1)` (provided ^ is the XOR operator in your language)

Answer (score 2):

You're system is an extension of boolean logic, (except for &&, || between values and ! around certain values, you also uses outcomes based solely on one truth-value, although there are multiple truth values). So normal approaches won't work, I've looked at the K-Map and I don't think it's going to work here.

You could combine all the A,B,C,...'s in all possible combinations, possibly introducing new values for all possible subsets (to handle (A || B) && C) and then try out all possible combination of operators on all of these subsets to see if one of the combination of operators holds for all combinations, and then finally infer a rule maybe with Dynamic Programming you can speed this up a bit, but it's going to be slow for anything more than a couple of values, and it's going to be cumbersome to program. (it's going to be at well over O(n^3) to find these rules)

A quicker/easier/faster but more memory costing solution is just to store all possible combinations that are true (or all that are false, depending on which list is shorter) in a hashtable/dictionary/array.

Comment: i think a k-map will work, but i need it to handle strings not zeros and ones

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to generate an optimized solution by analyzing the truth table's [K-map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) and then writing your expression.

Answer (score 0):

There's lot of literature on doing this by hand; see Karnaugh maps.
You can automate one of those techniques.

But in essence what you want to do is to construct a naive boolean equation representing your truth table, and then applied a symbolic boolean simplifier (or minimizer) to that equation (Hardware language synthesizers do this as part of their code generation process).

Constructing the naive equation is easy: build a conjunction for each row of
your truth table which produces true, and take the disjunction of all the conjunctions.  Your first table would produce the naive equation:

```
 (~a & ~b)  |  (a & ~b)
```

If you applied boolean simplification to this:

```
  ((~a | a) & ~b)  // combine terms
  (TRUE & ~b )    // consequence of ~a | a
  ~b  // the answer
```

Your second table would produce the naive equation:

```
 (~a & b) | (a & ~b )
```

Which doesn't simplify further.

You can use a [program transformation system](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/ProgramTransformation.html) to accomplish this.  Such a system typically allows you to define a parser for your input language (in this case, the truth tables), and to define transformations from your input langauge to the output language, and more transformations on the output language.  Your input-to-output transformation would map the truth table notation to the boolean equation notation.  Transformations on the boolean equations would then carry out the simplifications.

Once you have a simplified formula, then you want to apply yet another set of transformations to map from pure boolean algebra into your final computer language, in your case, PHP.

We've done this kind of thing quite often with our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html).  DMS brings some nice help to problem: it understands associate and commutative algebraic rewrites, which makes producting the simplification equations easier and more robust in the face of complicated formulas.

We've applied DMS to algebraic boolean formulas with literally hundreds of thousand of literals (terms of the form of A or ~A) in a number of cases. One example was a code generator that accepted a description of how to control a factory (literally) in terms of sensors (reading the factory state) and actuators (things that change the factory state), genrrated the equations, simplified them, and then translated them to multiple different target computer languages for industrial controllers called PLCs.

You can see an example, not of boolean simplification, but of [real algebraic simplification](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/SimpleDMSDomainExample.html) using DMS.  Boolean simplification is easier to write :-}

Answer (score 0):

I think CKen (http://cken.sourceforge.net/) (is good for you).

CKen supports both ''upper cases'' and ''lower cases'', so it supports 58 (= 2x29) single variables!

And the most important, multi-expressions can be used in it (by separators):

Example: `a,b,c,d,e;(a+b)*c;d*e#a;`

On the other hand, it is very fast!

---

**You must define your variables before using it (variables) in your expressions.**

Comment: This generates truth tables and calculates values. It does not generate the code that the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

**Introduction**

It is relatively easy to generate many different types of coding styles from a Petri Net model of an application logic. Given a Petri Net model of a truth table it might be easier to use this model for transforming a truth table into code with "all proper optimizations" or code based on your understanding.

"[How to Translate a Truth Table into Computer Code using Petri Nets](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/373275825_How_to_Translate_a_Truth_Table_into_Computer_Code_using_Petri_Nets_Manually_and_Automatically)" provides an example of a Petri Net model of a truth table and three types of generated code based on the Petri Net model.

**Example**

The following is the example from the article. Consider Table 1 where A, B are inputs while X, Y and Z are outputs (Juan, 2011):

**Table 1 the Exemplar Truth Table**

| Row No. | A | B | X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

Table 2 - Table 6 represent a Petri Net model for the Exemplar Truth Table. Figure 1 is a Petri Net diagram of the Petri Net model.

In Table 2 the value for each input or output in Table 1 is kept in the mark of a place (m): m_0 for input B, m_1 for input A, m_2 for output X, m_3 for output Y and m_4 for output Z. An extra pace P5 is used to make sure an enabled transition fires once only. If a new set of input values were specified then m_5 should be initialized to 1.

**Table 2 Place Marks**

| Type | pID | Prop |
| --- | --- | --- |
| P | 0 | `m_0` |
|  | 1 | `m_1` |
|  | 2 | `m_2` |
|  | 3 | `m_3` |
|  | 4 | `m_4` |
|  | 5 | `m_5` |

Each row in Table 1 in is a transition in Table 3.

**Table 3 Transition Status**

| Ty | tID | Pp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| T | 0 | `s_t_0` |
|  | 1 | `s_t_1` |
|  | 2 | `s_t_2` |
|  | 3 | `s_t_3` |

In Table 4 an input from the place to the transition exists for each input entry of Table 1. An extra input exists from P5 to each of the transitions. Every input has a test for updating (iE_in) the status of the input (s_in).

**Table 4 Input Status and Logics**

| Ty | eID | pID | tID | Pp | iE_in |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| In | 0 | 0 | 0 | `s_in_0` | `iE_in_0` |
|  | 1 | 1 | 0 | `s_in_1` | `iE_in_1` |
|  | 2 | 5 | 0 | `s_in_2` | `iE_in_2` |
|  | 3 | 0 | 1 | `s_in_3` | `iE_in_3` |
|  | 4 | 1 | 1 | `s_in_4` | `iE_in_4` |
|  | 5 | 5 | 1 | `s_in_5` | `iE_in_5` |
|  | 6 | 0 | 2 | `s_in_6` | `iE_in_6` |
|  | 7 | 1 | 2 | `s_in_7` | `iE_in_7` |
|  | 8 | 5 | 2 | `s_in_8` | `iE_in_8` |
|  | 9 | 0 | 3 | `s_in_9` | `iE_in_9` |
|  | 10 | 1 | 3 | `s_in_10` | `iE_in_10` |
|  | 11 | 5 | 3 | `s_in_11` | `iE_in_11` |

In Table 5 an output from the transition to the pace exists for each output entry in Table 1. Every output has logic for updating (fE_ou) the mark of the corresponding place (m).

**Table 5 Output Logics**

| Ty | eID | pID | tID | fE+ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ou | 0 | 2 | 0 | `fE_ou_0` |
|  | 1 | 3 | 0 | `fE_ou_1` |
|  | 2 | 4 | 0 | `fE_ou_2` |
|  | 3 | 2 | 1 | `fE_ou_3` |
|  | 4 | 3 | 1 | `fE_ou_4` |
|  | 5 | 4 | 1 | `fE_ou_5` |
|  | 6 | 2 | 2 | `fE_ou_6` |
|  | 7 | 3 | 2 | `fE_ou_7` |
|  | 8 | 4 | 2 | `fE_ou_8` |
|  | 9 | 2 | 3 | `fE_ou_9` |
|  | 10 | 3 | 3 | `fE_ou_10` |
|  | 11 | 4 | 3 | `fE_ou_11` |

In Table 6 every transition has a test (iE_T) for combining the status of inputs (s_t). The logical operation for combining the status of inputs is the AND operation. Every transition has an update logic (fE_T) for calling on the update logics of outputs (fE_ou).

**Table 6 Transition Status and Logics**

| Ty | tID | Pp | iE_T | fE_T |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| T | 0 | `s_t_0` | `iE_T_0` | `fE_T_0` |
|  | 2 | `s_t_1` | `iE_T_1` | `fE_T_1` |
|  | 3 | `s_t_2` | `iE_T_2` | `fE_T_2` |
|  | 4 | `s_t_3` | `iE_T_3` | `fE_T_3` |

In Figure 1 every place is a circle and every transition is a square. The number in each circle is the pID (place identifier). The number in each transition is the tID (transition identifier). An input is a connector from a circle to a square. An output is a connector from a square to a circle. The input identifier (eID) and the output identifier (eID) are not shown. The annotation values of annotations (e.g. m, s_in, s_t, iE_in, fE_ou, iE_T, fE_T) are not shown but they are available in Table 2 - Table 6.

[Figure 1 A Petri Net Diagram of the Exemplar Truth Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfuFO.jpg)

**Example Implementations**

The Petri Net model of the exemplar truth table should be considered a specification. From this specification there are many ways to implement the code. For example "Net Elements and Annotations" include guidelines for implementing Petri Net models into JavaScript code (Chionglo, 2014). Some of these guidelines were used for the code generated in Sample Code 1, Sample Code 2 and Sample Code 3. [Warning: Sample Code 3 have not been tested on a breadboard prototype.]

**Sample Code 1**

```
/* Copyright 2023 John Frederick Chionglo */
function PN$6382759469(parms) {
  this.id = parms.id;
}
PN$6382759469.objs = [];
with (PN$6382759469) {
  prototype.cid = 6382759469;
  prototype.id = undefined;
  prototype.np = 6;
  prototype.nt = 4;
  prototype.ni = 12;
  prototype.no = 12;
  prototype.nn = 1;
  prototype.nr = 1;
  prototype.iE_in_0 = function() {
    this.s_in_0 = ( (this.m_0<1) ? false : true );
  };

  prototype.iE_in_1 = function() {
    this.s_in_1 = ( (this.m_1<1) ? false : true );
  };

  prototype.iE_in_2 = function() {
    this.s_in_2 = ( (this.m_5<1) ? false : true );
  };

  prototype.iE_in_4 = function() {
    this.s_in_4 = ( (this.m_1<1) ? false : true );
  };

  prototype.iE_in_5 = function() {
    this.s_in_5 = ( (this.m_5<1) ? false : true );
  };

  prototype.iE_in_6 = function() {
    this.s_in_6 = ( (this.m_0<1) ? false : true );
  };

  prototype.iE_in_8 = function() {
    this.s_in_8 = ( (this.m_5<1) ? false : true );
  };

  prototype.iE_in_11 = function() {
    this.s_in_11 = ( (this.m_5<1) ? false : true );
  };

  prototype.fE_in_2 = function() {
    this.m_5 -= 1;
  };

  prototype.fE_in_5 = function() {
    this.m_5 -= 1;
  };

  prototype.fE_in_8 = function() {
    this.m_5 -= 1;
  };

  prototype.fE_in_11 = function() {
    this.m_5 -= 1;
  };

  prototype.iE_in_3 = function() {
    this.s_in_3 = ( (this.m_0<1) ? true : false );
  };

  prototype.iE_in_7 = function() {
    this.s_in_7 = ( (this.m_1<1) ? true : false );
  };

  prototype.iE_in_9 = function() {
    this.s_in_9 = ( (this.m_0<1) ? true : false );
  };

  prototype.iE_in_10 = function() {
    this.s_in_10 = ( (this.m_1<1) ? true : false );
  };

  prototype.fE_ou_0 = function() {
    this.m_2 = 1;
  };

  prototype.fE_ou_4 = function() {
    this.m_3 = 1;
  };

  prototype.fE_ou_8 = function() {
    this.m_4 = 1;
  };

  prototype.fE_ou_11 = function() {
    this.m_4 = 1;
  };

  prototype.fE_ou_1 = function() {
    this.m_3 = 0;
  };

  prototype.fE_ou_2 = function() {
    this.m_4 = 0;
  };

  prototype.fE_ou_3 = function() {
    this.m_2 = 0;
  };

  prototype.fE_ou_5 = function() {
    this.m_4 = 0;
  };

  prototype.fE_ou_6 = function() {
    this.m_2 = 0;
  };

  prototype.fE_ou_7 = function() {
    this.m_3 = 0;
  };

  prototype.fE_ou_9 = function() {
    this.m_2 = 0;
  };

  prototype.fE_ou_10 = function() {
    this.m_3 = 0;
  };

  prototype.iE_T_3 = function() {
    this.iE_in_9();
    this.iE_in_10();
    this.iE_in_11();
    this.s_t_3 = this.s_in_9 && this.s_in_10 && this.s_in_11;
  };

  prototype.fE_T_3 = function() {
    this.fE_in_11();
    this.fE_ou_9();
    this.fE_ou_10();
    this.fE_ou_11();
  };

  prototype.iE_T_2 = function() {
    this.iE_in_6();
    this.iE_in_7();
    this.iE_in_8();
    this.s_t_2 = this.s_in_6 && this.s_in_7 && this.s_in_8;
  };

  prototype.fE_T_2 = function() {
    this.fE_in_8();
    this.fE_ou_6();
    this.fE_ou_7();
    this.fE_ou_8();
  };

  prototype.iE_T_1 = function() {
    this.iE_in_3();
    this.iE_in_4();
    this.iE_in_5();
    this.s_t_1 = this.s_in_3 && this.s_in_4 && this.s_in_5;
  };

  prototype.fE_T_1 = function() {
    this.fE_in_5();
    this.fE_ou_3();
    this.fE_ou_4();
    this.fE_ou_5();
  };

  prototype.iE_T_0 = function() {
    this.iE_in_0();
    this.iE_in_1();
    this.iE_in_2();
    this.s_t_0 = this.s_in_0 && this.s_in_1 && this.s_in_2;
  };

  prototype.fE_T_0 = function() {
    this.fE_in_2();
    this.fE_ou_0();
    this.fE_ou_1();
    this.fE_ou_2();
  };

  prototype.pEv_T_3 = function() {
    this.fE_T_3();
    this.iE_T_0();
    this.iE_T_1();
    this.iE_T_2();
    this.iE_T_3();
  };

  prototype.pEv_T_2 = function() {
    this.fE_T_2();
    this.iE_T_0();
    this.iE_T_1();
    this.iE_T_2();
    this.iE_T_3();
  };

  prototype.pEv_T_1 = function() {
    this.fE_T_1();
    this.iE_T_0();
    this.iE_T_1();
    this.iE_T_2();
    this.iE_T_3();
  };

  prototype.pEv_T_0 = function() {
    this.fE_T_0();
    this.iE_T_0();
    this.iE_T_1();
    this.iE_T_2();
    this.iE_T_3();
  };
}
```

**Sample Code 2**

```
/* Copyright 2023 John Frederick Chionglo */
function PN$6382759469(parms) {
  this.id = parms.id;
}
PN$6382759469.objs = [];
with (PN$6382759469) {
  prototype.cid = 6382759469;
  prototype.id = undefined;
  prototype.np = 6;
  prototype.nt = 4;
  prototype.ni = 12;
  prototype.no = 12;
  prototype.nn = 1;
  prototype.nr = 1;
  (function(ia, pa) {
    var str, j;
    for (j=0; j<ia.length; j++) {
      str = "prototype.iE_in_" + ia[j] + " = function() {\n";
      str += "  this.s_in_" + ia[j] + " = ( (this.m_" + pa[j] + "<1) ? false : true );\n";
      str += "};\n";
      eval(str);
    }
  })(
    [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 11],
    [0, 1, 5, 1, 5, 0, 5,  5]
  );
  (function(ia, pa) {
    var str, j;
    for (j=0; j<ia.length; j++) {
      str = "prototype.fE_in_" + ia[j] + " = function() {\n";
      str += "  this.m_" + pa[j] + " -= 1;\n";
      str += "};\n";
      eval(str);
    }
  })(
    [2, 5, 8, 11],
    [5, 5, 5,  5]
  );
  (function(ia, pa) {
    var str, j;
    for (j=0; j<ia.length; j++) {
      str = "prototype.iE_in_" + ia[j] + " = function() {\n";
      str += "  this.s_in_" + ia[j] + " = ( (this.m_" + pa[j] + "<1) ? true : false );\n";
      str += "};\n";
      eval(str);
    }
  })(
    [3, 7, 9, 10],
    [0, 1, 0,  1]
  );
  (function(oa, pa) {
    var str, j;
    for (j=0; j<oa.length; j++) {
      str = "prototype.fE_ou_" + oa[j] + " = function() {\n";
      str += "    this.m_" + pa[j] + " = 1;\n";
      str += "};\n";
      eval(str);
    }
  })(
    [0, 4, 8, 11],
    [2, 3, 4,  4]
  );
//  })(
//    [0, 4, 6, 11],
//    [2, 3, 2,  4]
//  );
  (function(oa, pa) {
    var str, j;
    for (j=0; j<oa.length; j++) {
      str = "prototype.fE_ou_" + oa[j] + " = function() {\n";
      str += "    this.m_" + pa[j] + " = 0;\n";
      str += "};\n";
      eval(str);
    }
  })(
    [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10],
    [3, 4, 2, 4, 2, 3, 2,  3]
  );
//  })(
//    [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10],
//    [3, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 2,  3]
//  );
  (function(nt, iia, fia, foa) {
    var str, j;
    do {
      nt -= 1;
      str = "  prototype.iE_T_" + nt + " = function() {\n";
        for (j=0; j<iia[nt].length; j++) {
          str += "  this.iE_in_" + iia[nt][j] + "();\n";
        }
        str += "  this.s_t_" + nt + " = this.s_in_" + iia[nt][0];
        for (j=1; j<iia[nt].length; j++) {
          str += " && this.s_in_" + iia[nt][j];
        }
        str += ";\n";
      str += "};\n";
      eval(str);
      str = "prototype.fE_T_" + nt + " = function() {\n";
        for (j=0; j<fia[nt].length; j++) {
          str += "  this.fE_in_" + fia[nt][j] + "();\n";
        }
        for (j=0; j<foa[nt].length; j++) {
          str += "  this.fE_ou_" + foa[nt][j] + "();\n";
        }
      str += "};\n";
      eval(str);
    } while (nt>0);
  })(
    prototype.nt,
    [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11]],
    [      [2],       [5],       [8],        [11]],
    [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11]]
  );
  (function(nt, pad, pat) {
    var str, j;
    do {
      nt -= 1;
      str = "prototype.pEv_T_" + nt + " = function() {\n";
      str += "  this.fE_T_" + nt + "();\n";
        for (j=0; j<pat[nt].length; j++) {
          str += "  this.iE_T_" + pat[nt][j] + "();\n";
        }
      str += "};\n";
      eval(str);
    } while (nt>0);
  })(
    prototype.nt,
    [[2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4, 5]],
    [[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3]]
  );
  prototype.im = function() {
    this.m_0 = 0;
    this.m_1 = 0;
    this.m_2 = 0;
    this.m_3 = 0;
    this.m_4 = 0;
    this.m_5 = 1;
  };
  prototype.rai = undefined;
  prototype.ipn = function() {
    var str, j;
    for (j=0; j<this.nt; j++) {
      eval("this.iE_T_" + j + "();");
    }
  };
}
```

**Sample Code 3**

```
// Copyright 2023 John Frederick Chionglo

// Input Pins
#define A 6
#define B 4
#define C 2

// Output Pins
#define X 8
#define Y 10
#define Z 12

boolean s_in_0 = false;
boolean s_in_1 = false;
boolean s_in_2 = false;
boolean s_in_3 = false;
boolean s_in_4 = false;
boolean s_in_5 = false;
boolean s_in_6 = false;
boolean s_in_7 = false;
boolean s_in_8 = false;
boolean s_in_9 = false;
boolean s_in_10 = false;
boolean s_in_11 = false;

boolean s_t_0 = false;
boolean s_t_1 = false;
boolean s_t_2 = false;
boolean s_t_3 = false;

byte m_0 = 0;
byte m_1 = 0;
byte m_2 = 0;
byte m_3 = 0;
byte m_4 = 0;
byte m_5 = 0;

void iE_in_0() {
  s_in_0 = ( (m_0<1) ? false : true );
}

void iE_in_1() {
  s_in_1 = ( (m_1<1) ? false : true );
}

void iE_in_2() {
  s_in_2 = ( (m_5<1) ? false : true );
}

void iE_in_4() {
  s_in_4 = ( (m_1<1) ? false : true );
}

void iE_in_5() {
  s_in_5 = ( (m_5<1) ? false : true );
}

void iE_in_6() {
  s_in_6 = ( (m_0<1) ? false : true );
}

void iE_in_8() {
  s_in_8 = ( (m_5<1) ? false : true );
}

void iE_in_11() {
  s_in_11 = ( (m_5<1) ? false : true );
}

void fE_in_2() {
  m_5 -= 1;
}

void fE_in_5() {
  m_5 -= 1;
}

void fE_in_8() {
  m_5 -= 1;
}

void fE_in_11() {
  m_5 -= 1;
}

void iE_in_3() {
  s_in_3 = ( (m_0<1) ? true : false );
}

void iE_in_7() {
  s_in_7 = ( (m_1<1) ? true : false );
}

void iE_in_9() {
  s_in_9 = ( (m_0<1) ? true : false );
}

void iE_in_10() {
  s_in_10 = ( (m_1<1) ? true : false );
}

void fE_ou_0() {
  m_2 = 1;
}

void fE_ou_4() {
  m_3 = 1;
}

void fE_ou_8() {
  m_4 = 1;
}

void fE_ou_11() {
  m_4 = 1;
}

void fE_ou_1() {
  m_3 = 0;
}

void fE_ou_2() {
  m_4 = 0;
}

void fE_ou_3() {
  m_2 = 0;
}

void fE_ou_5() {
  m_4 = 0;
}

void fE_ou_6() {
  m_2 = 0;
}

void fE_ou_7() {
  m_3 = 0;
}

void fE_ou_9() {
  m_2 = 0;
}

void fE_ou_10() {
  m_3 = 0;
}

void iE_T_3() {
  iE_in_9();
  iE_in_10();
  iE_in_11();
  s_t_3 = s_in_9 && s_in_10 && s_in_11;
}

void fE_T_3() {
  fE_in_11();
  fE_ou_9();
  fE_ou_10();
  fE_ou_11();
}

void iE_T_2() {
  iE_in_6();
  iE_in_7();
  iE_in_8();
  s_t_2 = s_in_6 && s_in_7 && s_in_8;
}

void fE_T_2() {
  fE_in_8();
  fE_ou_6();
  fE_ou_7();
  fE_ou_8();
}

void iE_T_1() {
  iE_in_3();
  iE_in_4();
  iE_in_5();
  s_t_1 = s_in_3 && s_in_4 && s_in_5;
}

void fE_T_1() {
  fE_in_5();
  fE_ou_3();
  fE_ou_4();
  fE_ou_5();
}

void iE_T_0() {
  iE_in_0();
  iE_in_1();
  iE_in_2();
  s_t_0 = s_in_0 && s_in_1 && s_in_2;
}

void fE_T_0() {
  fE_in_2();
  fE_ou_0();
  fE_ou_1();
  fE_ou_2();
}

void pEv_T_3() {
  fE_T_3();
  iE_T_0();
  iE_T_1();
  iE_T_2();
  iE_T_3();
}

void pEv_T_2() {
  fE_T_2();
  iE_T_0();
  iE_T_1();
  iE_T_2();
  iE_T_3();
}

void pEv_T_1() {
  fE_T_1();
  iE_T_0();
  iE_T_1();
  iE_T_2();
  iE_T_3();
}

void pEv_T_0() {
  fE_T_0();
  iE_T_0();
  iE_T_1();
  iE_T_2();
  iE_T_3();
}

void ipnpevr() {
  m_0 = digitalRead(B);
  m_0 = ( (m_0==1) ? 0 : 1 );

  m_1 = digitalRead(A);
  m_1 = ( (m_1==1) ? 0 : 1 );

  m_5 = digitalRead(C);
  m_5 = ( (m_5==1) ? 0 : 1 );

  iE_T_0(); if (s_t_0) { fE_T_0(); digitalWrite(X, m_2); digitalWrite(Y, m_3); digitalWrite(Z, m_4); return; }
  iE_T_1(); if (s_t_1) { fE_T_1(); digitalWrite(X, m_2); digitalWrite(Y, m_3); digitalWrite(Z, m_4); return; }
  iE_T_2(); if (s_t_2) { fE_T_2(); digitalWrite(X, m_2); digitalWrite(Y, m_3); digitalWrite(Z, m_4); return; }
  iE_T_3(); if (s_t_3) { fE_T_3(); digitalWrite(X, m_2); digitalWrite(Y, m_3); digitalWrite(Z, m_4); return; }
}

void setup() {
  pinMode(A, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(B, INPUT_PULLUP);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(B), ipnpevr, FALLING);
  pinMode(C, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(X, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Y, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Z, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {}
```

**Conclusion**

If you find it challenging to generate the type of code you wish to generate from a truth table then it may help to create a Petri Net diagram of the turth table and then generate the type of code from the Petri Net model.

**References**

Chionglo, J. F. (2014). Net Elements and Annotations for Computer Programming: Computations and Interactions in PDF. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/275347172_Net_Elements_and_Annotations_for_Computer_Programming_Computations_and_Interactions_in_PDF.

Chionglo, J. F. (2023). How to Translate a Truth Table into Computer Code using Petri Nets Manually and Automatically. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/373275825_How_to_Translate_a_Truth_Table_into_Computer_Code_using_Petri_Nets_Manually_and_Automatically.

Juan (2011). How to turn truth table into smallest possible if/else bock. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/102757/how-to-turn-truth-table-into-smallest-possible-if-else-block. (Aug. 3, 2023).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34882760)